# Zend Framework: How to delete without where

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, sql-delete

I want to delete a record in mysql using "LIMIT" and without "WHERE".

The sql should look like this:

> "DELETE * FROM table_name LIMIT 10"

This query will delete first 10 records in the table.

Here is my code (i was trying to delete from raw query, but doesn't success, nothing happen after i run this):

```
$query = 'DELETE * FROM table_name LIMIT 10';
$db = $this->getDbTable()->getDefaultAdapter();
$result = $db->query($query);
```

About the **delete()** in zend framework, as far as i know, it must be include **WHERE** in the conditions.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: I don't know why nothing is happening, but you should be including an `ORDER BY` clause if you plan to use `LIMIT`.

Comment: as far as i research, that query will delete first 10 records, so i don't think we need an order by here. but thanks for the helps.

Comment: Well, your research was incorrect. Without an order by clause mysql will delete the records as it encounters them. There is no guarantee that mysql encounters the records in the order you want the records to be deleted.

Comment: Check basics for delete syntax. There's no `DELETE * FROM [table_name]` syntax. Never asterisk (`*`) sign was used in delete syntax. [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html) is your friend.

Comment: @Tpojka right, i wasn't notice that .. thanks you.